# Lambda type parameter must be derived from System.Delegate

Tags: c#, lambda

In a `C#` project, I want to create an extension that would take a list of property names and create a dynamic select query.

I found [magic Gist](https://gist.github.com/volak/20f453de023ff75edeb8) that seems to be doing exactly that. However, [var lambda = ...](https://gist.github.com/volak/20f453de023ff75edeb8#file-magic-cs-L15) keeps throwing the following error

> Lambda type parameter must be derived from System.Delegate

Here is the code

```
public static IQueryable<dynamic> ToDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<String> fields)
{
    var pocoType = typeof(T);

    var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(pocoType, "x");
    var members = fields.Select(f => Expression.PropertyOrField(itemParam, f));
    var addMethod = typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).GetMethod(
                "Add", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(object) });


    var elementInits = members.Select(m => Expression.ElementInit(addMethod, Expression.Constant(m.Member.Name), Expression.Convert(m, typeof(object))));

    var expando = Expression.New(typeof(ExpandoObject));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>>(Expression.ListInit(expando, elementInits), itemParam);

    return query.Select(lambda.Compile());
}
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793736/how-do-i-create-an-expressionfunc-with-type-parameters-from-a-type-variable

Comment: Google it. It is very simple: https://iamabhik.wordpress.com/tag/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate-because-it-is-not-a-delegate-type/

Answer (score 1):

In `Expression.Lambda<T>` expression `T` is considered *lambda type parameter* that *must be derived from System.Delegate*. So you just need to remove wrapping `Expression` and also there is no need to call `Compile` at the end since `IQueryable` expect to receive `Expression<Func<T, F>>` and not a `Func<T, F>` which is for `IEnumerable`

```
//..
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(Expression.ListInit(expando, elementInits), itemParam);

return query.Select(lambda);
```

Comment: Thank you! Although the `var lambda = ...` is no longer throwing the previous exception, I am getting the following error ` Only list initializer items with a single element are supported in LINQ to Entities.` when calling the method `users.ToDynamic(fields).ToList();`

Comment: @MikeA A quick fix would be change method to return `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and change `return` statement to `return query.AsEnumerable().Select(lambda.Compile());` but it means that query won't be executed in database but on client

Comment: The whole purpose of doing what I am trying to do is to do the select on the database, not in memory. Is there a way do this on the database server?

Comment: @MikeA Well, it's not possible with `Dictionary` or with `ExpandoObject` but I can try to investigate a solution with list contains key-value pairs.